# How to generate random time for current date?

Tags: java, random, time

When i convert to milliseconds the time shows different time for different **DATES**. How can i generate the same time for current date.

**CODE:**

```
final Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
final LocalTime time = new LocalTime(random.nextLong());
System.out.println(time);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get the `LocalDate` for `now` and then add a random `LocalTime` with a random value for `hours` (0-24], `minutes` (0-60], `seconds` (0-60] and `nanoseconds` (0, 999999999]. Then display your `LocalDateTime`. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), 
            LocalTime.of(random.nextInt(24), random.nextInt(60),
            random.nextInt(60), random.nextInt(999999999 + 1)));
    System.out.println(time);
}
```

Comment: Sticking to millisecond, I'd use `LocalTime.ofNanoOfDay(random.nextInt(86400000) * 1000000L)` for the time-of-day part. --- Also, be aware that OP was using Joda-Time's `LocalTime`, not `java.time` *(Java 8 `LocalTime` doesn't have any public constructors)*.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch how can i convert that (time) to miliseconds ?

Comment: @VaishakBabu `System.out.println(time.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant().toEpochMilli());`

Comment: @Elliott Frisch i get the value as (2017-01-24T00:45).. how can i format it to (00:45)

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly you can do something like the following

```
MillisecondsToStartOfTodayFromEpoch + (timeOtherDateInMilliseconds % MilliSecondsPerDay)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `LocalTime` you're using is [`org.joda.time.LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html), not `java.time.LocalTime` *(can't be)*, and you want the random time-of-day with todays date, just call [`toDateTimeToday()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#toDateTimeToday()).

```
DateTime datetime = time.toDateTimeToday();
```